# How can I create a framework with pod dependencies in it?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods

I saw many tutorials by the developers which are not proved to be very helpful for me to in this area. Some of them are old a few are now like year old but when I follow them them the same thing is not happening on my end,
Please help me regarding this situation.

I successfully make the framework and it was successfully invoke by my app and works fine but when I install pod files it build without error in the framework and when I tried to run it in the app it shows error and build is failing.

Pods like Alamofire and charts

suppose the name of my framework is X , When I use "Import X" to import the frame in app and pods are install in it it shows Alamofire not found and Algorithm not found and sometime this Multiple commands produce '/Users/ground1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoFrameworkApp-brctkulvbepfgafuygquzhveljkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DemoApp.app/CHANGELOG.md'

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting

Comment: @sahilsaini please [edit] your question with additional info, don’t put it in the comments. See also [ask].

Comment: You can’t, frameworks can’t include frameworks